# ServiceStack with Xamarin on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, xamarin, servicestack

Are there any step by step instructions on how to create a servicestack project using Xamarin on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

The step-by-step instructions for [building a web service from scratch](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) should also apply to Xamarin Studio as well. Otherwise you can start from a copy of one of the [live demos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos) instead.